# Rspec Failing After Phantomjs upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, phantomjs, capybara, poltergeist

I have updated phantomjs to latest version (2.1.1) after updating it to latest version my rspec started failing using capybara, phantomjs and for javascript poltergeist

it seems like after upgrading phantomjs to latest version and on visiting a page using in rspec with feature js: true the element doesn't update with the result and previous data still shows in the DOM element

Code Sample:

```
let!(:data) { FactoryGirl.create(:data) }
let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

before do 
  login_as(user)
end


feature "user browses  page", js: true do
  context 'document' do
   it 'should show documents on it' do
     visit url
     expect(page).to have_content("Content")  #This test gets pass 
     expect(page).to have_content(data.display_name) #here it fails
   end
  end
end

**Error : 
expected page to have "data_2" in "data_1"**
```

Comment: how is your `login_as` method defined? Does it have an expectation at the end to make sure it waits until the login has completed?

Comment: login_as is the helper method provided by devise gem and also i tried the wait_for_ajax concept but then also it was not working

Comment: Have you tried looking at `page.html` to see what's actually on the page?  Have you checked that the case of the string you're looking for matches what is shown on the page?

Comment: Yes I checked it, Example: 

Page.html

"Data in the page having content as data_1" -- this comes when my first context runs

and then when above context runs it still gives me the same page with 
"Data in the page having content as data_1" -- But expecting data_2 instead of data_1